# Marking values from the previous N number of days in KDB based on criteria?

Tags: kdb

**Initial Table**

```
company time         value  
-------------------------
a       00:00:15.000  100
a       00:00:30.000  100
b       00:01:00.000  100
a       00:01:10.000  100
a       00:01:15.000  100
a       00:01:20.000  300
a       00:01:25.000  100
b       00:01:30.000  400
a       00:01:50.000  100
a       00:02:00.000  100
a       00:00:03.000  200
```

**Let `t` = 1 hour.**

For each row, I would like to look back `t` time.

Entries falling in `t` will form a time window. I would like to get `max(time window) - min (time window) / number of events)`.

For example, if it is `12:00` now, and there are a total of five events, `12:00, 11:50, 11:40, 11:30, 10:30`, four of which falls in the window of `t` i.e. `12:00, 11:50, 11:40, 11:30`, the result will be `12:00 - 11:30 / 4`.

Additionally, the window should only account for rows with the same value and company name.

**Resultant Table**

```
company time         value   x
--------------------------------
a       00:00:15.000  100    0 (First event A).
a       00:00:30.000  100    15 (30 - 15 / 2 events).
b       00:01:00.000  100    0 (First event of company B).
a       00:01:10.000  100    55/3 = 18.33 (1:10 - 0:15 / 3 events).
a       00:01:15.000  100    60/4 = 15 (1:15 - 0:15 / 4 events).
a       00:01:20.000  300    0 (Different value).
a       00:01:25.000  100    55/4 = 13.75 (01:25 - 0:30 / 4 events).
b       00:01:30.000  400    0 (Different value and company).
a       00:01:50.000  100    40/4 = 10 (01:50 - 01:10 / 4 events). 
a       00:02:00.000  100    50/5 = 10 (02:00 - 01:10 / 5 events).
a       00:03:00.000  200    0 (Different value).
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. If it helps, I asked a similar question, which worked splendidly: [Sum values from the previous N number of days in KDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57034144/sum-values-from-the-previous-n-number-of-days-in-kdbprevious-n-number-of-days-in-kdb)

**Table Query**

```
([] company:`a`a`b`a`a`a`a`b`a`a`a; time: 00:00:15.000 00:00:30.000 00:01:00.000 00:01:10.000 00:01:15.000 00:01:20.000 00:01:25.000 00:01:30.000 00:01:50.000 00:02:00.000 00:03:00.000; v: 100 100 100 100 100 300 100 400 100 100 200)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may wish to use the following;

```
q)update x:((time-time[time binr time-01:00:00])%60000)%count each v where each time within/:flip(time-01:00:00;time) by company,v from t
company time         v   x
---------------------------------
a       00:15:00.000 100 0
a       00:30:00.000 100 7.5
b       01:00:00.000 100 0
a       01:10:00.000 100 18.33333
a       01:15:00.000 100 15
a       01:20:00.000 300 0
a       01:25:00.000 100 13.75
b       01:30:00.000 400 0
a       01:50:00.000 100 10
a       02:00:00.000 100 10
a       03:00:00.000 200 0
```

It uses `time binr time-01:00:00` to get the index of the min time for the previous 1 hour of each time.

Then `(time-time[time binr time-01:00:00])%60000` gives the respective time range (i.e., time - min time) for each time in minutes.

`count each v where each time within/:flip(time-01:00:00;time)` gives the number of rows within this range.

Dividing the two and implementing `by company,v` applies it all only to those that have the same `company` and `v` values.

Hope this helps.

Kevin

Answer (score 1):

If your table is ordered by time then below solution will give you the required result. You can also order your table by time if it is not already using `xasc`.

I have also modified the table to have time with different hour values.

```
 q) t:([] company:`a`a`b`a`a`a`a`b`a`a`a; time: 00:15:00.000 00:30:00.000 01:00:00.000 01:10:00.000 01:15:00.000 01:20:00.000 01:25:00.000 01:30:00.000 01:50:00.000 02:00:00.000 03:00:00.000; v: 100 100 100 100 100 300 100 400 100 100 200)

 q) f:{(`int$x-x i) % 60000*1+til[count x]-i:x binr x-01:00:00}

 q) update res:f time by company,v from t
```

```
Output
company time         v   res       
---------------------------------
a       00:15:00.000 100 0       
a       00:30:00.000 100 7.5     
b       01:00:00.000 100 0       
a       01:10:00.000 100 18.33333
a       01:15:00.000 100 15      
a       01:20:00.000 300 0       
a       01:25:00.000 100 13.75   
b       01:30:00.000 400 0       
a       01:50:00.000 100 10      
a       02:00:00.000 100 10      
a       03:00:00.000 200 0
```

You can modify the function `f` to change time window value. Or change `f` to accept that as an input parameter.

**Explanation:**

We pass time vector by company, value to a function `f`. It deducts 1 hour from each time value and then uses `binr` to get the index of the first time entry within 1-hour window range from the input time vector.

```
q) i:x binr x-01:00:00
q) 0 0 0 0 1 2 2
```

After that, it uses the indexes of the output to calculate the total count. Here I am multiplying the count by 60000 as time differences are in milliseconds because it is casting it to `int`.

```
q) 60000*1+til[count x]-i
q) 60000 120000 180000 240000 240000 240000 300000
```

Then finally we subtract the min and max time for each value and divide them by the above counts. Since time vector is ordered(ascending), the input time vector can be used as the max value and min values are at indexes referred by `i`.

```
q) (`int$x-x i) % 60000*1+til[count x]-i
```